# Updating unused field after initial creation does not work rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

For reference, this is using Rails 3.0.9.

I can't seem to figure out why, but I cannot update a field which was left blank at the initial creation of the object/row.

If my model looks like this:

name - string

date - date

message - string

If I put info in all of the fields upon initial creation, everything can be updated without a hitch later on. But if I do not put info in one of the fields, say the title, I cannot update that field after initial creation.

I'm not doing anything out of the ordinary, the form is pretty plain jane:

```
<%= form_for @event do |f| %>
   <%= f.error_messages %>
   <p>
      <%= f.label :name %><br />
      <%= f.text_field :name %>
   </p>
   <p>
      <%= f.label :date %><br />
      <%= f.date_select :date %>
   </p>
   <p>
      <%= f.label :message %><br />
      <%= f.text_field :message %>
   </p>
   <p><%= f.submit %></p>
<% end %>
```

And my controller is equally as simple:

```
def update
   if @event.update_attributes(params[:event])
       redirect_to @event, :notice  => "Successfully updated event."
   else
       render :action => 'edit'
   end
end
```

And the model:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :races, :dependent => :destroy
has_many :price_groups, :dependent => :destroy

accepts_nested_attributes_for :races, :reject_if => lambda{ |a| a[:name].blank? }, :allow_destroy => true
accepts_nested_attributes_for :price_groups, :reject_if => lambda{ |a| a[:name].blank? }, :allow_destroy => true

attr_accessible :name, :date, :message, :races_attributes, :price_groups_attributes
end
```

Comment: "I cannot update" means the new value simply doesn't get assigned? Or not persisted to the DB? Or does it fail with an error?

Comment: I've added the model.

When I update, if I have the console of the server open, I can see the post but what is being sent over in the post does not include the fields updated. So say message was left empty when I first created, and then I update it, in the post it just says "message"=>"" or something along those lines.

It does not fail with an error, and is not persisted.

Comment: so you don't see any error-messages in the form? or is the action redirected to the event? what is the params hash saying when you post the update action?

Comment: I have the same issue.  Cannot update a datetime field initially not set at creation.  I can update another datetime field that is not null but not the one that is null.  Weird.